# Tensorflow: What's the difference between the use of tf.mat_fn() or tf.nn.dynamic_rnn() to apply layers before an LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

This question is about coding strategy using Tensorflow. I would like to create a small classifier network made of:

- 1: an input
- 2: a simple layer fully connected (W*x+B)
- 3: a LSTM layer
- 4: a softmax layer
- 5: an ouput

In tensorflow, to use the class tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(), we need to a batch of sequences to the network. So far, it's work perfectly (I love this library).

But as I want to apply a simple layer on each features of my sequences (2nd layer in my description), i'm wondering:

- Do i preceed my LSTM layer with this simple layer and pass both to the [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard8/tf.nn.dynamic_rnn.md) operation...

OR

- Do i use the function [tf.map_fn()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard1/tf.map_fn.md) twice (one to unpack batches, one to unpack sequences), which if a understood well, is able to unpack my sequences and apply a layer on each features line.

Normally, it should give me the same result ? If it's the case, what should I use ?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar scenario, where I'd like to chain recurrent and non-recurrent layers.

> Do i preceed my LSTM layer with this simple layer and pass both to the
>   tf.nn.dynamic_rnn() operation...

This won't work. The function `dynamic_rnn` expects a cell as its first argument. A cell is a class that inherits from `tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell`. Additionally, the second input argument to `dynamic_rnn` should be a tensor with at least 3 dimensions, where the first two dimensions are batch and time (`time_major=False`) or time and batch (`time_major=True`).

> Do i use the function tf.map_fn() twice (one to unpack batches, one to unpack sequences), which if a understood well, is able to unpack my sequences and apply a layer on each features line.

This might work, but doesn't appear to me to be an efficient and clean solution. Firstly, it should not be necessary to 'unpack batches', as you presumably want to perform some operation on batches of features and time-steps, where each observation in a batch is independent from the others.

My solution to this particular problem was to create a sub-class of `tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell`. In my case I wanted a simple feedforward layer that would iterate over all of the time steps and that could be used in `dynamic_rnn`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class FeedforwardCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
  """A stateless feedforward cell that can be used with MultiRNNCell
  """
  def __init__(self, num_units, activation=tf.tanh, dtype=tf.float32):
    self._num_units = num_units
    self._activation = activation
    # Store a dummy state to make dynamic_rnn happy.
    self.dummy = tf.constant([[0.0]], dtype=dtype)

  @property
  def state_size(self):
    return 1

  @property
  def output_size(self):
    return self._num_units

  def zero_state(self, batch_size, dtype):
    return self.dummy

  def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    """Basic feedforward: output = activation(W * input)."""
    with tf.variable_scope(scope or type(self).__name__):  # "FeedforwardCell"
      output = self._activation(tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear(
        [inputs], self._num_units, True))
      return output, self.dummy
```

An instance of this class can be passed, in a list with "normal" RNN cells, to an `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell` initializer. The resulting object instance can be passed as the `cell` input argument to `dynamic_rnn`.

Important to note: `dynamic_rnn` expects that a recurrent cell returns a state when called. I therefore use `dummy` in `FeedforwardCell` as a fake state variable.

My solution might not be the smoothest or best way to chain recurrent and non-recurrent layers together. I'd be interested in hearing from other Tensorflow users about their suggestions.

**Edit**
If you choose to use the `sequence_length` input argument of `dynamic_rnn`, then `state_size` should be `self._num_units` and the `dummy` state should have shape `[batch_size, self.state_size]`. In other words, the state cannot be a scalar. Note that `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` requires that the `sequence_length` argument is not `None`, whereas `dynamic_rnn` does not have this requirement. (This is weakly documented in the TF documentation.)